# Trying Convert Address to Lat Lang but Giving me error Over_Query_Limit in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, distance, latitude-longitude

Actually I want to get lat lang from address through  google api and then using that lat lang i wanna get distance with my current lat lang which right know I have hard coded but its giving me error of Over_Query_Limit.
I tried different way but did not work. Please guide me how can I avoid from this problem.

This is my PHP Script code:

```
<?php
    $address = 'iqra university islamabad';
    $url = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($address)."&sensor=false");
    sleep(2);
    $response = json_decode($url);
    if ($response->status == 'OK') {
        $latitude = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
       GetDrivingDistance(33.651936,$latitude,73.064366,  $longitude);
           echo '<br />';
        echo 'Latitude: ' . $latitude;
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Longitude: ' . $longitude;


    } else {
        echo $response->status;
    }



    function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2)
    {
        $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=pl-PL";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
        $dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
        $time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
       echo 'distance: ' . $dist;
       //return array($dist,$time);
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: When using google maps API, you must use an APIKEY in the query. Anonymous queries are very limited.

Comment: could you guide me please how can I add api key I am new to php

Comment: and what kind of API key should be?

Comment: if you need a *key* for the Google Maps *API* I would venture to guess that you need a *Google Maps API Key*.

Comment: I have added Geocoding Api but now its giving me error of REQUEST_DENIED

Comment: Try using only `https` in API urls